# How do I set SFX option when creating one from the command line?

Tags: batch-file, winrar

Here is my batch file command:

```
set rar_path=C:\Program Files\WinRAR
"%rar_path%\rar" a -sfx "MyArchive" Folder1 Folder2 File1.exe File2.exe
```

How do I set the sfx creation options?  Specifically I want the self-executable to auto-run a file after it is finished extraction it to a set location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

```
set rar_path=C:\Program Files\WinRAR
"%rar_path%\rar" a -sfx -z"YOUR CONFIG FILE.conf" "MyArchive" Folder1 Folder2 File1.exe File2.exe
```

And here is the CONFIG file:

```
Silent=1
Overwrite=1
Path=FOLDER NAME IN PROGRAM FOLDER
Setup=FILE TO RUN AFTER IT FINISH.EXE
```

Answer (score 0):

with the script on answer 1
with the Config file do you have to make that before you compress
and where do you put it if you have to make before compressing